# How to get Jquery scrollTop adjust to halfway in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the div to snap to the center of the viewport, right now it just snaps to the top. I added `$(window).scrollTop() / 2)` but that didn't seem to work.

*EDIT*

I forgot to include the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/84/

```
var body = $("html, body");
var items = $(".item");
var animating = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    if (!animating) {
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {

            items.each(function(key, value) {
                if ($(value).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() / 2) {
                    animating = true;
                    $(body).stop().animate( { scrollTop: $(value).offset().top }, 1000,'swing');
                    setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 2000);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }, 50));
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're scrolling the body to align with the div. Is that what you want to do but have it scroll so that the div is in the middle of the viewport?

Comment: It scrolled to the top of the page because that's where 0 is as far as the computer is concerned, so what you want to do is take the number you already have add half of the screen height (putting the top of your div in the center of the page)  minus half of the div height (moving the div up to center)

Comment: You do want to be carful with this though because mobile compatibility can be tricky when creating things like this. For instance it isn't so easy if the div is longer then the screen.

Comment: Hmm like make an invisible div halfway on the page so that that's what touches the top?